# how to insert option value into database with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i need to insert my option value into database with this option view :

```
<label>Add Time</label>:
<select id="dropdownHolder" name="restaurant_busy">
    <option value="1">30 minute</option>
    <option value="2">1 hour</option>
    <option value="3">1 hour 30minute</option>
    <option value="4">2 hour</option>
</select>
```

this the controller what i have done :

```
function change_restaurant(){
    if(!isset($_COOKIE["vendor_login"])){ redirect("/VENDOR",'refresh'); }
    if(!$this->Token_m->m_check_token($this->input->cookie('vendor_login'),$this->input->cookie('vendor_token'))){
        setcookie('vendor_login', '', time() - 3600, '/');
        redirect('/VENDOR/',"refresh");
    }
    if ($this->input->cookie('vendor_login') != null) {
        $admin_name = $this->input->cookie('vendor_login');

        setcookie('vendor_login', $admin_name, time() + 28800, '/');
        $msg = $this->input->cookie('vendor_token');
        setcookie('vendor_token', $msg, time() + 28800, '/');
    }
    if($vendorname = $_COOKIE["vendor_login"]) {
        $check_login = $this->Vendor_m->m_get_user_by_vendor($vendorname);
        $restaurant_id = $check_login["restaurant_id"];
        {
            if ($_POST = NULL){
                redirect("/VENDOR/Vendor/restaurant_setting","refresh");
            }
            $data = array(
            "restaurant_info"=>$this->input->post("restaurant_info"),
            'restaurant_busy' => $this->input->post("restaurant_busy")
            );
            $this->Vendor_m->m_update_restaurant_info( $data,$restaurant_id);
            $this->db->last_query();
        }
    }redirect("/VENDOR/Vendor/restaurant_setting","refresh");
}
```

this the model :

```
function m_update_restaurant_info($restaurant_info, $restaurant_id)
{
    $this->db->where("restaurant_id", $restaurant_id);
    $this->db->update("uhd_restaurant", $restaurant_info);
}
```

that its my option value, in my database there is a table name "uhd_restaurant" and the field is "restaurant_busy", in restaurant_busy there are some comments like : 0=no busy(as default), 1=30 minute, 2=1 hour, 3=1 hour 30 minute, 4= 2 hour.

if i select 30minute, in restaurant_busy must be 1, what should i do in controller and in model?

and after i submit it i got this following error :

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'restaurant_info' in 'field list'
>
> UPDATE `uhd_restaurant` SET `restaurant_info` = NULL,
>   `restaurant_busy` = NULL WHERE `restaurant_id` = '250'
>
> Filename:
>   C:/Data_web/food.km/application/models/VENDOR/SG/Vendor_m.php
>
> Line Number: 554

Comment: Your life would be a lot easier if you added values that had meaning. 30, 60, 90, and 120 would be better values here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with single quotes.
I think following line

```
$data = array(
        "restaurant_info"=>$this->input->post("restaurant_info"),
        'restaurant_busy' => $this->input->post("restaurant_busy")
        );
```

should be

```
$data = array(
        'restaurant_info' =>$this->input->post("restaurant_info"),
        'restaurant_busy' => $this->input->post("restaurant_busy")
        );
```